# Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException'

Tags: php, symfony, parsing, fosuserbundle, fatal-error

this is my first time working a project with symfony 3.3 
i installed it and everything is good , now i want to install FOSuserBundle , i followed all steps in symfony site . the last step is to :Update your database schema  ( php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force ) 
but i had this exception : 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException' with message 'Indentation problem at line 34 (near " main:").' in C:\wamp64\www\untitled\vendor\symf
ony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser.php:591
Stack trace:

## 0 C:\wamp64\www\untitled\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser.php(320): Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser->getNextEmbedBlock()

## 1 C:\wamp64\www\untitled\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser.php(450): Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser->doParse('encoders:\n    F...', 2816)

## 2 C:\wamp64\www\untitled\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser.php(320): Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser->parseBlock(7, 'encoders:\n    F...', 2816)

## 3 C:\wamp64\www\untitled\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser.php(450): Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser->doParse('security:\n    e...', 2816)

## 4 C:\wamp64\www\untitled\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser.php(320): Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser->parseBlock(6, 'security:\n    e in C:\wamp64\www\untitled\

vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\FileLoader.php on line 179

**this is my ..app/config/security.yml**

security:

```
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
```

security:
       encoders:
           FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

```
   role_hierarchy:
       ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
       ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

   providers:
       fos_userbundle:
           id: fos_user.user_provider.username

   firewalls:
       main:
           pattern: ^/
           form_login:
               provider: fos_userbundle
               csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager # Use form.csrf_provider instead for Symfony <2.4
           logout:       true
           anonymous:    true

   access_control:
       - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
       - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
       - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
       - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate
        #http_basic: ~

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html
        #form_login: ~
```

please help me 
thanks :)

Comment: Post your `.../app/config/security.yml`

Comment: i added it in my post

Comment: if this is a direct copy paste of your security.yml file, then role_hierarchy, providers, firewalls, access_control, main,  seem to be only 3 spaces indented instead of 4.

Answer (score 0):

This is really tough to notice, but...

There is an extra space before the `main:` that appears after the `access_control:` block. Remove the space and you should be good to go.

I found this by copying your file into Netbeans IDE. It's pretty good at identifying YAML file errors.

Good luck.

Comment: Same error message? If you continue to get YAML parse errors try creating your project in Netbeans and use it to view your YAML files. Symfony YAML files are quite strict about spaces and such.